# Does JPA saveall method uses hibernate batch to update/insert

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've 1000 entities to update in MySQL database so If I use `myRepository.saveAll(List<Entity>)` does it internally use hibernate batch to update the table. I'm using below hibernate property for batch update/insert

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
```

I'm wondering if JPA will execute 10 queries to update in batch or will work same as JPA `save(Entity)` method and execute 1000 queries to update ? Is there any way to trace it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`saveAll()` is just a loop calling `save()` on each entity. It can't be anything else, as JPA doesn't have any method to save several entities at once.

Does that mean that hibernate batching isn't used? No, because Hibernate batching precisely consists in grouping insert queries in batches, and execute the batches.

Comment: Hey @Nizet, In the above mentioned case batching will be used or not?

Comment: I already answered that question: *Does that mean that hibernate batching isn't used? No.*